# В обход dependency injection symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Потихоньку осваивая symfony 4 возникли недопонимания.
Имеется абстрактный репозиторий в который inject-ица некий DriverManager объект-коннекшн к базе данных. От него отнаследованы конкретные репозитории, но в примере будет фигурировать один ConcreteRepository.

```php
abstract class AbstractRepository {
   public function __construct(DriverManager $dm) {
      $this->driverManager = $dm;
   }
}

class ConcreteRepository extends AbstractRepository {
   public function save($object) {
      // use DriverManage and save $object
   }
}
```

Это использовалось примерно вот так(в console-команде как пример)

```php
class ConcreteCommand extends Command {
   public function __construct(ConcreteRepository $cr) {
      $this->cr = $cr;
   }

   public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
      ...
      $result = $this->cr->save($object);
   }
}
```

Далее возникла необходимость создать некую фабрику репозиториев и тут сталкиваюсь с проблемой. Мне нужно через все слои прокинуть DriverManager к конкретному репозиторию:

```php
/**
 *
 */
class RepositoryFactory {
   public function __construct(DriverManager $dm) {
      $this->dm = $dm;
   }

   public function create($type) {
      if($type === 'concrete-repository') {
         return new ConcreteRepository($this->dm);
      }
   }
}

/**
 * 
 */
class ConcreteCommand extends Command {
   public function __construct(DriverManager $dm) {
      $this->dm = $dm;
   }

   public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
      $repo = (new RepositoryFactory($this->dm))->create('concrete-repo');
   }
}
```

Выглядит как-то странно, как можно избежать данной проблемы с прокидыванием DriverManager через все слои?

PS: По ряду причин доктрину использовать нет возможности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что мешает сделать прямо так:

```
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, RepositoryFactory $factory) {
  $repo = $factory->create('concrete-repo');
```

}

я попробовал у себя только не на консольный команде а в контроллере:

```
/**
 * Ваш первый вариант с прямым вызовов репозитория
 * @Route("/concrete", name="concrete")
 */
public function concrete(ConcreteRepository $repo) {

    $repo->save(['test']);

    return new Response(
        '<html><body>concrete</body></html>'
    );
}

/**
 * Через фабрику
 * @Route("/factory", name="factory")
 */
public function factory(RepositoryFactory $factory) {

    $repo = $factory->create('concrete-repository');
    if ($repo) {
        $repo->save(['test']);
    }
    return new Response(
        '<html><body>factory</body></html>'
    );
}
```

Собсно фабрика и классы репозиториев ваши:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Service\DriverManager;

class RepositoryFactory {
    /**
     * @var DriverManager
     */
    protected $dm;

    public function __construct(DriverManager $dm) {
        $this->dm = $dm;
    }

    public function create($type) {
        if($type === 'concrete-repository') {
            return new ConcreteRepository($this->dm);
        }
        throw new \Exception('Unknown type of Repo');
    }
}
```

Репы

```
use App\Service\DriverManager;

class AbstractRepository {
    /**
     * @var DriverManager
     */
    protected $driverManager;

    public function __construct(DriverManager $driverManager) {
        $this->driverManager = $driverManager;
    }
}

namespace App\Repository;

class ConcreteRepository extends AbstractRepository {
    public function save ($object) {
        $this->driverManager->anythingDo($object);
    }
}
```

и некий DriveManager

```
namespace App\Service;

class DriverManager {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function anythingDo($object) {
        echo self::class . ' anythingDo with: ' . print_r($object, true) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

я сам только изучаю и стало любопытно

Comment: Это у меня после Yii диссонанс в голове). Вы правы я точно так же и сделал, только обертку некую добавил в виде DocumentManager и использую его где необходимо. Получилось так: $this->documentManager->getRepository(MyDocument::class)->findOne($id).